# ListView with custom ImageView

Tags: android

I have a problem that is being bugging me for almost 3 days. I have a ListView with a Custom Array Adapter. Everything pretty standard. Then, in the layout, I have a Custom ImageView. I think there is a problem with the Custom ImageView because on scroll the image disappear.

I made a little test and add a rectangle onDraw() method and it always show. I have also add a normal ImageView and it always shows as well.

The problem is with the Custom View that sometimes show the image and other don't.

Here is some code

**Custom View**

```
 public class CropTopImageView extends ImageView {
        private static Paint paint;

        public CropTopImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CropTopImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CropTopImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
          paint = new Paint();
          paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
          paint.setColor(Color.RED);
          paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {

        Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
        float scale;
        int viewWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        int viewHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        int drawableWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int drawableHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
            scale = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
        } else {
            scale = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
        }

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);http://imageshack.us/a/img560/8381/example3g.png
    }

        // This is just a test
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

          int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();
          int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();

          // Draw a border
          canvas.drawRect(10, 10, width-10, height-10, paint);
    }
}
```

**Adapter getView**

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("CardView", "getView " + position + " " + convertView);
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.cardImage = (CropTopImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.cardImage);

        return convertView;
    }
```

XML Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
>

    <com.td.fs.android.customview.CropTopImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardImage"
        android:layout_width="246dp"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:src="@drawable/card_visa_blue"
     />

    <com.td.fs.android.customview.CropTopImageView
        android:id="@+id/pocketImage"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/holder_pocket" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pocketImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="92dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home_dashboard_picker" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ImageView is always showing. 
onDraw is always showing.
CropTopImageView src image shows the first time than randomly disappear/appear.

I don't know if I can show some images because it a project for a company.

**UPDATE**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In adapter getview() why don't you put holder.cardImage = within the if statement?

Comment: This was a test to check if it solve the problem. Either in the if statement or out, the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm not sure this is the answer but we might as well use this as an error log ;)

The paint you use is static which is a big nono if it is something you want to remember. I'd try to remove static.

Comment: The paint was only to check if the view was showing.I draw something so check if it was only the image in src that disappear or the whole custom view. Turns out it is just the image in src.

Comment: The code does not break. It's just the visual that is inconsistent.

Comment: Here are some images. This happen when I scroll the view.
[image1](http://imageshack.us/a/img689/671/example1e.png)
[image2](http://imageshack.us/a/img266/4723/example2s.png)
[image3](http://imageshack.us/a/img560/8381/example3g.png)